# Finding a injective mapping to prove the countability of $ \mathscr{P}_{\text{fin}}(\mathbb{N}) $.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have an assignment due Friday, and I have been struggling with one of the problems, which seemed to be easy enough at first glance. I have been working on it for a few days now and still cannot come up with any smart ideas.

I am asked to find an injective mapping 
$$ \varphi_k : \mathscr{P}_k(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathbb{N}^k $$
where $ \mathscr{P}_k(\mathbb{N}) $ is the set of all subsets of the natural numbers with exactly k elements. From there I am supposed to proceed to prove that $ \mathscr{P}_{\text{fin}}(\mathbb{N}) $, the set of all finite subsets of the natural numbers, is countable.

I do not have a problem with the latter part, but I have tried to find such a mapping for days, but I seem to be missing some key concept.

I have tried all commutative operations, but always end up with two function values being the same for different sets. Vectors obviously don't work, at least not in a straight forward way, since 
$$ \varphi_2(\{1, 2\}) = (1, 2) \neq (2, 1) = \varphi_2(\{2, 1\})$$
and $ \{1, 2\} = \{2, 1\}$.
Can anyone get me on the right track?

Your help is most appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I voted to reopen because the question is not just about finding _some_ proof that there are countably many finite subsets of $\mathbb N$, but about difficulties with applying a _particular hint_. The duplicate candidates Asaf found (see the edit history) do not concern that specific hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the hint you're trying to apply, you're not asked to find a *bijection* $\mathcal P_k(\mathbb N)\to\mathbb N^k$, but merely an *injective* mapping. So you're free to simply decide to let $\varphi_k(A)$ consist of the elements of $A$ in *increasing order*, for example.