# Injective map $\phi _k :P_k (\mathbb{N})\rightarrow \mathbb{N}^k$

Tags: analysis, natural-numbers

Let $\mathbb{P}_k (\mathbb{N})$ be the set of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with $k\geq 1$ elements.

Find an injective map $\phi _k :\mathbb{P}_k (\mathbb{N})\rightarrow \mathbb{N}^k$

(Beware, the sets $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,1\}$ are identical so your map should be contructed such that $\phi _2 :(\{1,2\})=\phi _2 :(\{2,1\})$

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Coming up with an injective map. Tried formulating different ways to map it into N^k but it breaks down whenever I increase k.

Comment: Which of $k = 1, 2, 3$ can you do?

Comment: How did you define $\phi_2?$

Comment: k=1, not sure about k>1.

Defined $\phi _2$ as the injective map which sends the sets of subsets of N with 2 elements to N^2.

Comment: Oddly similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940919/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $S\subset\Bbb N$ of cardinality $k$, sort the elements in ascending order $a_1<a_2<\ldots <a_k$ and map to $(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$. This makes $\phi_2(\{1,2\})=\phi_2(\{2,1\})=(1,2)$.

Alternatively (i.e., without explicit sorting): Map to the elementary symmetric polynomials. In particular $\phi_2(\{x,y\})=(x+y,xy)$, $\phi_3(\{x,y,z\})=(x+y+z,yz+xz+xy,xyz)$, etc.

Comment: The sorting makes it injective?

Comment: sorting makes it well defined, injectivity is obvious

Comment: The symmetric polynomials trick is really clever.